# Show an Activity once in application

Tags: android, android-activity, history

Hi
In my application I have a splash Activity and a Disclaimer activity ... .
 In Disclaimer there is 2 buttons. First one is "Agree" and another is "Disagree". When I agree it will move to another activity. 
But when I again run the app the Disclaimer page is coming. 
I dont want to see the disclaimer activity again once selecting Agree button.

In onClickListner of Agree button I have used : intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

But still it is not solved.

Answer (score 4):

Uses preferences: when you click agree, set a custom preference to remember if the user has agreed:

```
SharePreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.edit()
    .putBoolean("user_agreed", true)
    .commit();
```

Then you can decide if you have to show the disclaimer:

```
SharePreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean hasAgreed = prefs.getBoolean("user_agreed", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreference for this and store a flag value in SharedPreference  and check the flag in your first activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a boolean to preferences. The first time you run you verify if boolean is true (default = false), it returns false you show the disclaimer.

Second time, you verify boolean, returns true, continue without showing.